# Eigen values and Eigen vectors

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, matrices

Let A be a 4x4 matrix with real entries such that $ \ -1,1,2,-2 \ $ are its eigen values.If $B=A^4-5A^2+5I$ ,where $I$ denotes the 4x4 identity matrix ,then which of the following statements are correct?

```
        (1)det(A+B)=0
        (2)det(B)=1
        (3)Trace (A-B)=0
        (4)Trace (A+B)=4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

To check the options we need two results:

- if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ then $P(\lambda)$ is an eigenvalue of $P(A)$ where $P$ is a given polynomial.
- If two matrices $A$ and $B$ commute *(and this is the case if $B=P(A)$)* then they are cotrigonalizable (diagonalizable) i.e. trigonalizable (diagonalizable) in the same basis.

Answer (score 0):

$A+B=A+A^4-5A^2+5I$ and $-1$ is an eigenvalue of $A$$\implies -1+(-1)^4-5(-1)^2+5$$=0$ is an eigenvalue of $A+B.$ (**$\implies$ 1 is correct**)

$\chi_A=(x+1)(x-1)(x+2)(x-2)=(x^2-1)(x^2-4)=x^4-5x^2+4.$ Due to the Cayley-Hamilton theorem, $A^4-5A^2+4I=0\implies B=I.$ (**$\implies$ 2 is correct**)

Since $-1,1,2,-2$ are its eigenvalues of $A,~\text{trace }A=-1+1+2-2=0.$ Also $\text{trace }B=4.$ So $\text{trace}(A+B)=4,\text{trace}(A-B)=-4.$ (**$\implies$3 is incorrect, 4 is correct**)